# Pass file name to .exe in registry key

Tags: c#, installation, registry

I have a small installer that installs some .exe and DLLs to the target machine, and sets a key in registry so that on right click on Excel files the user sees a new context menu item. This command key has for value something like :

**[TARGETDIR]myexecutable.exe %1**

The **%1** has for effect to pass the file name to my executable in **args[0]**. I expect this to give to my .exe the full path. But it gives me some sort of compressed path. For example for :

**C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\teestqqqq.xls**

it will give me :

**C:\DOCUME~1\user\Desktop\TEEST~1.XLS**

That's a problem for me. How can i solve this ? I need a proper full path.

*UPDATE : As requested in comments and in answers, this is an issue to me because from the path I receive I derive some new folder names. These folder names are to be committed so SVN repositories later on by some users. I have noticed that on some machines of my users, the .exe receive the sort path, and on other, the long path. My users consider the folder names to be "unique" for DIFF purposes on SVN. I just need a way to ensure uniqueness of the folder names (I think there is already what I need in answers below at the time of writing)*

Comment: That is the shortpath you get. Why is it a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
string shortName = @"C:\DOCUME~1\user\Desktop\TEEST~1.XLS";
string longName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(shortName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `%1` with `"%1"`, i.e. put quotes around, you'll get the long file name. The thing is 'Documents and Settings' has spaces in its name which can't be passed to your program correctly without quotes. That's why the shell converts the path to the short name, without spaces, and then passes it to your program.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Path.GetFullPath(path)
```

That should do it. But you should just be able to work with the short path.

Answer (score 1):

Long before "long file names". File names in MS DOS were limited to 8 characters for the name, followed by a dot and maximum of 3 characters for the extension. What you are seeing is the short version of the path with long file names. Here is a longer explanation: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000209.htm

Now explain how the given path is a problem for you? Because windows APIs should be able to work with the short file name versions as well.

As ken2k mentioned, `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(..)` will return the expanded path given a short file name path.

Quoting the documentation:

> If you pass in a short file name, it is expanded to a long file name.